# Parent-child ordering in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this-

```
id  name        ordering    catid 
1   parent1         1         0
2   parent2         2         0
3   parent3         3         0
4   child11         1         1
5   child12         2         1
6   child21         1         2
7   child22         2         2
8   child31         1         3
9   child32         2         3
```

I am trying to get the result like below-

```
id  name        ordering    catid 
1   parent1         1         0
4   child11         1         1
5   child12         2         1
2   parent2         2         0
6   child21         1         2
7   child22         2         2
3   parent3         3         0
8   child31         1         3
9   child32         2         3
```

I want to order the first `parent(catid=0)` than its child than second parent and its child.
Is this possible to achieve desire result with these column.I tried join but not succeeded.
Surely I am not doing it correctly.
This is what I have tried-

```
SELECT a.*,c.name AS category_title FROM table AS a 
LEFT JOIN table AS c ON c.id = a.catid 
ORDER BY c.ordering asc, a.ordering asc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query would do a `SELF JOIN` on the same table, by joining the records from the first table with the corresponding parent records. The column parentId would contain the parent Id of the record if the parent existed, otherwise the ID of the record itself. The results are then ordered by parentId and then by the ID so that the parent always appears at the top in a given group of parent and its children.

```
SELECT
    m.id, 
    m.name, 
    m.catid, 
    m.ordering, 
    p.ordering,
    case 
        WHEN p.ordering IS NULL THEN m.ordering * 10
        ELSE m.ordering + p.ordering * 10
    END AS parentId
FROM
    MyTable m
    LEFT JOIN MyTable p
    ON m.catid = p.id
ORDER BY parentId
```

The result is as follows:

```
1   parent1 0   1       10
4   child11 1   1   1   11
5   child12 1   2   1   12
2   parent2 0   2       20
6   child21 2   1   2   21
7   child22 2   2   2   22
3   parent3 0   3       30
8   child31 3   1   3   31
9   child32 3   2   3   32
```

Comment: Thanks,I tried your solution but Ordering is based on id but I want based on "ordering" field.For both parent and child.Any help.

Comment: The query in my response returns the records in the exact order you mentioned in your question. If you want to order them differently, by ordering column, then the ORDER BY clause should be `ORDER BY parentId AS, m.ordering ASC`.

Comment: Actually parent1 will be on the top because it's ordering is 1.If in case parent2 having the bigger id than it'll be on the top.And the query will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I got what you are saying!

Comment: Please see the updated query that considers the ordering of the parent and child to sort them (and doesn't rely on the ID).

Answer (score 0):

This can be one implementation I think though not sure how good it would be.

- Add an extra attribute to the table named *weight*.
- If any row is child then that weight would be
  (catid*maximum_id+ordeing) else weight would be (ordering*maximum_id)
  [It can be done by altering weight attribute two times for two
  condition]
- Now select what you need and sort by *weight*.
- Delete the column *weight* from table

Answer (score 0):

Calculation with IDs does not really work, you may get overflow if you have enough records.

This is better:

```
SELECT a.*,c.name AS category_title FROM table AS a 
LEFT JOIN table AS c ON c.id = a.catid 
ORDER BY 
case c.ordering when 0 then a.ordering else c.ordering, a.ordering
```